# ReactNative - Android extremely slow within may image views

Tags: react-native

I'm implementing a Home screen that have lots of image views. The concept is like Photoshop layers. Each layer is an image view (PNG). The screen contains 20-30 images. The assets are stored locally.

The app runs smoothly on iOS but it is extremely slow in Android.
My first solution is reducing the file sizes but it doesn't help much.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

react-native versions is 0.59.10.

Comment: have you tried using https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image?

Comment: Not yet. All images are store locally so should I use Fast Image?

Comment: Yes, for both dynamic and local images, fast image has better performance

Comment: @GauravRoy this would not make much of a difference for local images.

Answer (score 2):

use react-native-fast-image

https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

use webp format instead of png

put your images at android or ios app package

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable
```

Comment: Be very careful with this lib - it has huge problems with releasing memory (particularly in lists) and can cause crashes. I have had to remove it from 2 separate projects for this reason. Make sure you run ios profiler to see if it is working in your scenario.

Comment: I agree with @JamesTrickey, react-native-fast-image repository looks dead, be careful choosing this path https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/685

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things can do to improve your application performance.

**1. Reduce image size**

Use smaller sized images like a thumbnail.
Use PNG as opposed to JPG.
Convert your images to WebP format.

**2. Cache the images locally**

Since you are loading images from locally you don't need to focus on this.

**3. Avoiding Unnecessary Renders Using PureComponent**

*If you are using FlatList to render images,*

**4. Add initialNumToRender prop on your FlatList**

This defines how many items will be rendered for the first time.

**5. Define the key(`keyExtractor`) prop on your Item Component**

This will avoid re-render dynamically added or removed items.

**6. Use `getItemLayout` to skip measurement of dynamic content.**

Also, there is some prop called `maxToRenderPerBatch`, `windowSize` that you can use to increase the performance of the application.

Check [React Native Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) & [Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance) official docmentations for more informations.

Also, [check this article](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips) to improve the performance of FlatList.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion list. My home screen just contains multiple image layers. Each image has full screen size. Should I use FlatList in this case?

Comment: @AnhTran yes, if you are planning to display a list of images you need to used list views provided by react-native such as Flatlist or SectionList, unlike ScrollView.

Comment: Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dt436mxL/ .  I don't know how to apply the Flat List. Would you please give me an example. Sorry I'm just a newbie