# How to Optimize speed of React Native application and FalstList

Tags: react-native

I'm using React-Native-CLI where I have a screen that is using ScrollView and FlatList and multiple APIs and FlatList are inside the ScrollView that I think slowing my app. So, how can I resolve this problem..?

Comment: FlatList itself is extending ScrollView already, so you don't need another ScrollView. Try to remove the outer Scrollview, it should be fine then.

Comment: sometimes this might helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692156/9432559